# Obtaining Type of Scala Collection Variable

Tags: scala, traits, scala-collections

1. In the following code, what are the real types of objects stored in `l`, `s`, and `m`?  I know that `List`, `Set`, and `Map` are respectively `Abstract class`, `trait`, and `trait`, and they can't be instantiated; so the real type of `l` can't be `List[Int]`.

   `scala> val l = List(1,2,3)
   l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)`

   `scala> val s = Set (1,2,3)
   s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)`

   `scala> val m = Map(1->2)
   m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2)`
2. How do I find the real types of the above objects?  I used `:type` in REPL, but it gives me `List[Int]`, `Set[Int]`, `Map[Int,Int]`; but I'm looking for real type of the objects stored in the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getClass` to know the underlying class of the instance the variable is referring to. Then print the class using `getSimpleName` or Use `getName` to get fully qualified class name

## Ammonite REPL output

```
@ Set(1, 2, 3).getClass.getName
res10: String = "scala.collection.immutable.Set.Set3"

@  Set(1, 2, 3).getClass.getSimpleName
res2: String = "Set3"

@ List(1, 2, 3).getClass.getSimpleName
res3: String = "$colon$colon"

@ Map(1 -> 2).getClass.getSimpleName
res4: String = "Map1"

@ trait Parent
defined trait Parent

@ case class Child(value: Int) extends Parent
defined class Child

@ val a: Parent = Child(1)
a: Parent = Child(1)

@ a.getClass.getSimpleName
res8: String = "Child"
```

For multiple elements Set internally uses `HashTrieSet` implementation

```
@ Set((1 to 100): _*).getClass.getName
res3: String = scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet
```

## Set

Find `Set1`, `Set2`, `Set3`, `Set4` in Companion object `Set`

```
/*                     __                                               *\
**     ________ ___   / /  ___     Scala API                            **
**    / __/ __// _ | / /  / _ |    (c) 2003-2013, LAMP/EPFL             **
**  __\ \/ /__/ __ |/ /__/ __ |    http://scala-lang.org/               **
** /____/\___/_/ |_/____/_/ | |                                         **
**                          |/                                          **
\*                                                                      */



package scala
package collection
package immutable

import generic._
import parallel.immutable.ParSet

/** A generic trait for immutable sets.
 *  $setNote
 *  $setTags
 *
 *  @since 1.0
 *  @author Matthias Zenger
 *  @author Martin Odersky
 *  @define Coll `immutable.Set`
 *  @define coll immutable set
 */
trait Set[A] extends Iterable[A]
//                with GenSet[A]
                with scala.collection.Set[A]
                with GenericSetTemplate[A, Set]
                with SetLike[A, Set[A]]
                with Parallelizable[A, ParSet[A]]
{
  override def companion: GenericCompanion[Set] = Set


  /** Returns this $coll as an immutable set, perhaps accepting a
   *  wider range of elements.  Since it already is an
   *  immutable set, it will only be rebuilt if the underlying structure
   *  cannot be expanded to include arbitrary element types.
   *  For instance, `BitSet` and `SortedSet` will be rebuilt, as
   *  they require `Int` and sortable elements respectively.
   *
   *  When in doubt, the set will be rebuilt.  Rebuilt sets never
   *  need to be rebuilt again.
   */
  override def toSet[B >: A]: Set[B] = {
      // This way of building sets typically has the best benchmarks, surprisingly!
    val sb = Set.newBuilder[B]
    foreach(sb += _)
    sb.result()
  }

  override def seq: Set[A] = this
  protected override def parCombiner = ParSet.newCombiner[A] // if `immutable.SetLike` gets introduced, please move this there!
}

/** $factoryInfo
 *  @define Coll `immutable.Set`
 *  @define coll immutable set
 */
object Set extends ImmutableSetFactory[Set] {
  /** $setCanBuildFromInfo */
  implicit def canBuildFrom[A]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, Set[A]] = setCanBuildFrom[A]

  /** An optimized representation for immutable empty sets */
  @SerialVersionUID(-2443710944435909512L)
  private object EmptySet extends AbstractSet[Any] with Set[Any] with Serializable {
    override def size: Int = 0
    def contains(elem: Any): Boolean = false
    def + (elem: Any): Set[Any] = new Set1(elem)
    def - (elem: Any): Set[Any] = this
    def iterator: Iterator[Any] = Iterator.empty
    override def foreach[U](f: Any => U): Unit = ()
    override def toSet[B >: Any]: Set[B] = this.asInstanceOf[Set[B]]
  }
  private[collection] def emptyInstance: Set[Any] = EmptySet

  /** An optimized representation for immutable sets of size 1 */
  @SerialVersionUID(1233385750652442003L)
  class Set1[A] private[collection] (elem1: A) extends AbstractSet[A] with Set[A] with Serializable {
    override def size: Int = 1
    def contains(elem: A): Boolean =
      elem == elem1
    def + (elem: A): Set[A] =
      if (contains(elem)) this
      else new Set2(elem1, elem)
    def - (elem: A): Set[A] =
      if (elem == elem1) Set.empty
      else this
    def iterator: Iterator[A] =
      Iterator(elem1)
    override def foreach[U](f: A => U): Unit = {
      f(elem1)
    }
    override def exists(@deprecatedName('f) p: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
      p(elem1)
    }
    override def forall(@deprecatedName('f) p: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
      p(elem1)
    }
    override def find(@deprecatedName('f) p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = {
      if (p(elem1)) Some(elem1)
      else None
    }
    override def head: A = elem1
    override def tail: Set[A] = Set.empty
    // Why is Set1 non-final?  Need to fix that!
    @deprecatedOverriding("This immutable set should do nothing on toSet but cast itself to a Set with a wider element type.", "2.11.8")
    override def toSet[B >: A]: Set[B] = this.asInstanceOf[Set1[B]]
  }

  /** An optimized representation for immutable sets of size 2 */
  @SerialVersionUID(-6443011234944830092L)
  class Set2[A] private[collection] (elem1: A, elem2: A) extends AbstractSet[A] with Set[A] with Serializable {
    override def size: Int = 2
    def contains(elem: A): Boolean =
      elem == elem1 || elem == elem2
    def + (elem: A): Set[A] =
      if (contains(elem)) this
      else new Set3(elem1, elem2, elem)
    def - (elem: A): Set[A] =
      if (elem == elem1) new Set1(elem2)
      else if (elem == elem2) new Set1(elem1)
      else this
    def iterator: Iterator[A] =
      Iterator(elem1, elem2)
    override def foreach[U](f: A => U): Unit = {
      f(elem1); f(elem2)
    }
    override def exists(@deprecatedName('f) p: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
      p(elem1) || p(elem2)
    }
    override def forall(@deprecatedName('f) p: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
      p(elem1) && p(elem2)
    }
    override def find(@deprecatedName('f) p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = {
      if (p(elem1)) Some(elem1)
      else if (p(elem2)) Some(elem2)
      else None
    }
    override def head: A = elem1
    override def tail: Set[A] = new Set1(elem2)
    // Why is Set2 non-final?  Need to fix that!
    @deprecatedOverriding("This immutable set should do nothing on toSet but cast itself to a Set with a wider element type.", "2.11.8")
    override def toSet[B >: A]: Set[B] = this.asInstanceOf[Set2[B]]
  }

  /** An optimized representation for immutable sets of size 3 */
  @SerialVersionUID(-3590273538119220064L)
  class Set3[A] private[collection] (elem1: A, elem2: A, elem3: A) extends AbstractSet[A] with Set[A] with Serializable {
    override def size: Int = 3
    def contains(elem: A): Boolean =
      elem == elem1 || elem == elem2 || elem == elem3
    def + (elem: A): Set[A] =
      if (contains(elem)) this
      else new Set4(elem1, elem2, elem3, elem)
    def - (elem: A): Set[A] =
      if (elem == elem1) new Set2(elem2, elem3)
      else if (elem == elem2) new Set2(elem1, elem3)
      else if (elem == elem3) new Set2(elem1, elem2)
      else this
    def iterator: Iterator[A] =
      Iterator(elem1, elem2, elem3)
    override def foreach[U](f: A => U): Unit = {
      f(elem1); f(elem2); f(elem3)
    }
    override def exists(@deprecatedName('f) p: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
      p(elem1) || p(elem2) || p(elem3)
    }
    override def forall(@deprecatedName('f) p: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
      p(elem1) && p(elem2) && p(elem3)
    }
    override def find(@deprecatedName('f) p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = {
      if (p(elem1)) Some(elem1)
      else if (p(elem2)) Some(elem2)
      else if (p(elem3)) Some(elem3)
      else None
    }
    override def head: A = elem1
    override def tail: Set[A] = new Set2(elem2, elem3)
    // Why is Set3 non-final?  Need to fix that!
    @deprecatedOverriding("This immutable set should do nothing on toSet but cast itself to a Set with a wider element type.", "2.11.8")
    override def toSet[B >: A]: Set[B] = this.asInstanceOf[Set3[B]]
  }

  /** An optimized representation for immutable sets of size 4 */
  @SerialVersionUID(-3622399588156184395L)
  class Set4[A] private[collection] (elem1: A, elem2: A, elem3: A, elem4: A) extends AbstractSet[A] with Set[A] with Serializable {
    override def size: Int = 4
    def contains(elem: A): Boolean =
      elem == elem1 || elem == elem2 || elem == elem3 || elem == elem4
    def + (elem: A): Set[A] =
      if (contains(elem)) this
      else new HashSet[A] + elem1 + elem2 + elem3 + elem4 + elem
    def - (elem: A): Set[A] =
      if (elem == elem1) new Set3(elem2, elem3, elem4)
      else if (elem == elem2) new Set3(elem1, elem3, elem4)
      else if (elem == elem3) new Set3(elem1, elem2, elem4)
      else if (elem == elem4) new Set3(elem1, elem2, elem3)
      else this
    def iterator: Iterator[A] =
      Iterator(elem1, elem2, elem3, elem4)
    override def foreach[U](f: A => U): Unit = {
      f(elem1); f(elem2); f(elem3); f(elem4)
    }
    override def exists(@deprecatedName('f) p: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
      p(elem1) || p(elem2) || p(elem3) || p(elem4)
    }
    override def forall(@deprecatedName('f) p: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
      p(elem1) && p(elem2) && p(elem3) && p(elem4)
    }
    override def find(@deprecatedName('f) p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = {
      if (p(elem1)) Some(elem1)
      else if (p(elem2)) Some(elem2)
      else if (p(elem3)) Some(elem3)
      else if (p(elem4)) Some(elem4)
      else None
    }
    override def head: A = elem1
    override def tail: Set[A] = new Set3(elem2, elem3, elem4)
    // Why is Set4 non-final?  Need to fix that!
    @deprecatedOverriding("This immutable set should do nothing on toSet but cast itself to a Set with a wider element type.", "2.11.8")
    override def toSet[B >: A]: Set[B] = this.asInstanceOf[Set4[B]]
  }
}
```

Comment: But Set3 is not a class in API; what is Set3?  Or Map1?

Comment: @user1888243 Set1, Set2, Set2, Set3, Set4 are defined inside Set companion object

Comment: "Use `getClass` to know the underlying class of the variable" – `getClass` does not tell you the "class of the variable". Variables don't even *have* classes in Scala. Only objects have classes, but variables are not objects in Scala. Variables have *types*, but `getClass` does not tell you the type of a variable. It tells you the *class* of the *object*. Also, `getClass` is a *Java Reflection* method, which means it will only show you what can be represented *in Java*. And, being a Java method, it won't work on a non-Java implementation of Scala such as Scala.js, Scala-native, or Scala.NET.

Comment: fixed the wording. The OP seemed to be happy with reflection and looks like OP is working on JVM. Is not OP would not accept the answer